# Is there a place in Azure ARM Template Schema to configure DSC Automation?

Tags: json, powershell, azure, templates, dsc

I would like to be able to configure Azure Automation DSC to set itself up automatically (find the DSC configuration to apply, onboard the correct vm's as nodes).

Now, I could do this use simply using Azure PowerShell commands, but I'd like for it to be integrated into the automated deploy of my Azure resource group using the JSON template.  Is there a way to specify/declare the configuration of the DSC automation in the template?

Here is the [JSON schema for Azure Automation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-10-31/Microsoft.Automation.json) (I believe this is the latest version, not sure how to verify this).  **I don't see anything that mention DSC** in here.

If configuring DSC *does* exists within the Schema, where can I find docs/spec on this?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I understood the question, what are you after exactly? adding node to automation or?

Comment: Both adding nodes to Azure Automation DSC and importing the DSC configuration for those nodes to target.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver ??

Comment: also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think this is what I needed.  I guess I'm not very good at researching, because I have been googling for days and haven't come across these articles.  This is a prevalent problem for me, maybe I'm not familiar enough with the correct technical terms for my google search to be precise enough.

Comment: I think you could check the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates). In the web, there are many templates, you could find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is an existing example on GitHub Azure Quick Start Templates here (as mention by 4c74356b41):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/dsc-extension-azure-automation-pullserver